# Visa for checking in luggage in Vietnam

Tags: visas, airports, airport-transfer

This question is about luggage and transfer with separate flight tickets.

I'm in Vietnam now on a 30-day single-entry visa. I wish to go to Singapore before my visa expires. If I go, then I have to fly back to Vietnam to catch a flight to Europe. The airline that flies me to Vietnam from Singapore will not be the same as the airline that flies me to Europe. I have spoken to these two airlines, and they cannot transfer the luggage between flights.

My question is, do I really need to buy another 30-day visa just to check in my luggage in Vietnam?

Edit: I'm Swedish, but I can't apply for the 15-day visa within 30 days after the visa I have has expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no land-side transit visas in Vietnam. It's either the 30-day visa or the 15-day exemption, if you are eligible. Also, note that the 30-day cool-off period is for TWO 15-day visa exemptions. You can cumulate a 30-day visa and a 15-day exemption.

Comment: What do you mean by two 15-day visa? How does that work? Do you have a source where I can read more?

Comment: Did I say 15-day visa? No. I said 15-day exemption. That's the main point. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Vietnam#Visa_exemption